# My .htaccess not working :(

Tags: linux, .htaccess

Hello my htaccess does not work. what could be the error?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]*)/(.*)/?$ video.php?id=$1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which page are you accessing?

Comment: is http://videostelacuras.com/video/22/Gusano/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get error 404, url friendly not working.

Comment: Where is your htaccess file? Does going to `http://videostelacuras.com/video.php?id=22` work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded, then make sure you have `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride FileInfo` setup for the document root (where `http://example.com/` goes to). Then make sure `MultiViews` is turned off. Then put these rules in the htaccess file *in your document root*:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+video\.php\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /video/%1/? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/ video.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```